# Mixing f2py with distutils

Tags: python, distutils, f2py

I have a python package "trees", which contains myscript.py file which makes use of a fortran subroutine.

Normally I compile the fortran module with

```
f2py -c -m calctree calctree.f90
```

and I can then do

```
from trees import myscript
myscript.mysub()
```

which makes use of calctree.so

If I package everything with distutils by running

```
python ./setup.py sdist
```

where the contents of setup.py are

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='trees',
      version='0.1',
    packages=['trees']
    )
```

and specify "include trees/calctree.f90" in a MANIFEST.in file, I can include the .f90 file, but I don't know how to make it compile with f2py on the user's computer, and have the .so file placed in an appropriate place. Can anybody help?

Thank you!

Comment: No idea about a built-in solution, but you could just run the command yourself in the module before calling `setup` and then include the compiled file in the setup call.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the numpy.distutils.core module which has its own setup function. 
Your setup.py should look something like this (assuming the fortran files are in the directory named trees),

```
import numpy.distutils.core
import setuptools


# setup fortran 90 extension
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
ext1 = numpy.distutils.core.Extension(
    name = 'calctree',
    sources = ['trees/calc_tree.f90'],
    )


# call setup
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
numpy.distutils.core.setup( 

    name = 'trees',
    version = '0.1',        
    packages = setuptools.find_packages(), 
    package_data = {'': ['*.f90']}, 
    include_package_data = True,   
    ext_modules = [ext1],

)
```

That should be a start at least.